# Number of elements in a collection of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that there exists some set $A$ of sets $A_1, ..., A_k$ that are each a subset of ${1,...,n}$. In addition, for each element in $i \in {1,...,n}$ there is a counter $c_i$ that denotes how many sets in $A$ contain element $i$.

Based on this information in the counter values, is it possible to give some upper bound on the size of $A$?

Clarification: We know that such $A_1, ..., A_k$ must exist, but we do not know $k$. Actually, the aim is to bound the value of $k$ based on $c_i$.

Comment: @student You must be asking for something else. As mentioned earlier the size of $A$ is given to be $k$.

Comment: If the sets $A_i$ are all different, then $|A| = k$. otherwise $|A| \le k$, so $k$ is an upper bound in any case. Presumably you are looking for a tighter bound? Is there some relationship between $n$ and $k$? (For example, if $n\ge k$, then $A_i = \{i\}$ results in $|A| = k$.)

Comment: Possible restatement: $A$ is a set of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $c_i$ is the number of sets in $A$ having $i$ as a member. Given $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, what is the tightest upper bound on the number of sets in $A$?

Comment: I meant it as Harald Hanche-Olsen restated the problem. I'll fix the question